# NodeJS and MongoDB: Not able to update the database with new changes

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

This is my schema design inside Admin Model in MongoDB:

```
account: {
  status: {type: Number, default: 0},
  uuid: {type: String, default: uuid.v1()},
  createdOn: {type: Date, default: Date.now()}
}
```

I want to change the status. I am using moongose inbuilt function `findByIdAndUpdate()`
I am able to pass the id properly but the server response is 500

```
function changeAdminStatus(req, res, next) {
  getSuperAminById(req.params.id).then(function(data) {
    if(data.account.status == 1) {
      var id = req.params.id

      Admin.findByIdAndUpdate(id, {$push: {'account.status': 0}}, function(err, doc) {
        if(err) {
          res.sendStatus(500)
        }
        else if(doc) {
          res.sendStatus(200)
        }
        else {
          res.sendStatus(404)
        }
      })
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: `{$push: {'account.status': 0}}` $push is for array not for value, you need to change to `$set` like this `{$set: {'account.status': 0}}`

Comment: You should print the error, that will help you debug. `if(err) {console.error(err)}`

Comment: Also, you really should format your code properly! Especially, when you post it to SO. Often someone will fix it for you, like I did now, but I don't think you even tried.

Comment: @somallg It still gives error the error is                   
{ [MongoError: exception: The field 'account.status' must be an array but is of type NumberInt32 in document {_id: ObjectId('568486bc19d472281c52a0d1')}]
  name: 'MongoError',
  message: 'exception: The field \'account.status\' must be an array but is of type NumberInt32 in document {_id: ObjectId(\'568486bc19d472281c52a0d1\')}',
  errmsg: 'exception: The field \'account.status\' must be an array but is of type NumberInt32 in document {_id: ObjectId(\'568486bc19d472281c52a0d1\')}',
  code: 168

Comment: yes thanks a lot I will keep this in mind in fututre

Comment: Sorry man and thanks a lot Somallg, ok i go it $set is for array anyways what was I thinking, thank you again it works fine.